# Terraform error while using variable type map

Tags: terraform

I am trying to run a module where I am getting error as :

Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.

```
variable "vpc" {
  type = map(string)
  default = 
  {
    dev  = "vpc-1234567" 
    qa   = "vpc-2345678"
    prod = "vpc-3345679"
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not think you need quotes for the `dev`, `qa` and `prod`.

Comment: Even after removing the quotes I am getting the same error. I could read from the docs that from terraform v.12 usage map has been deprecated. https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/map.html. but not sure how to implement it.

Comment: You have a random trailing closing parenthesis there. I've voted to close as a typo for now because I don't think it's useful for others but hopefully that helps fix the problem for you.

Comment: sorry about that still getting same error

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Its not due to parenthesis. This would be second issue.

Comment: @Marcin still essentially a typo in my opinion. Just two of them.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have **new line** after default. It should be:

```
variable "vpc" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    "dev"  = "vpc-1234567" 
    "qa"   = "vpc-2345678"
    "prod" = "vpc-3345679"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcin it worked. I am getting another error as "Argument or block definition required" if this is for map?

Comment: @ManoharKumarSingh This seems as a new issue, thus new question would be better.

Comment: Thanks for your response. resolved one parentheses was missing.